# Remove AspnetVersioning ApiVersion from Swagger Doc

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Inside my route parameters I have need of the ApiVersion class, as shown below.

```
    [HttpGet("v{version:apiVersion}/Company/{companyId}/absence/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute]ApiVersion version, [FromRoute] int companyId, [FromRoute]int id)
    {...
```

However including this makes swagger try to bind the ApiVersion model and requests, GroupVersion, MajorVersion, MinorVersion and Status. Is there a way for me to always remove these properties as they don't need to be provided.

[image]

Comment: I would like to ask what your real demand is, is it the same as the solution provided below?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[BindNever]` to your `ApiVersion` attributes:

ApiVersion class example:

```
  public class ApiVersion
{
    [BindNever]
    public string GroupVersion { get; set; } = "aaa";

    [BindNever]
    public string MajorVersion { get; set; } = "bbb";

    [BindNever]
    public string MinorVersion { get; set; } = "ccc";

    [BindNever]
    public string Status { get; set; } = "ddd";
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: If my answer is useful to you, you can mark it as answer,that will help people who encounter the same problem in the future.

Comment: Hello thanks, for your answer. Unfortunately I don't have access to the class to set this as it is part of Microsoft asp-net versioning library.

https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/src/Common/ApiVersion.cs

Comment: @Lee,Then why must `ApiVersion` be written in the parameter? Just leave it alone.